# Ao clicar no item do tab o aplicativo fecha

Tags: ios, swift, webview, maps

Estou fazendo um aplicativo que possui um tab, no primeiro tab coloquei um webview, no segundo um mapa, quando entro no app e clico no item de mapa, o app fecha, o erro acontece depois que eu faço referencia do mapa ao ViewController

log:
2018-09-11 17:21:54.849452-0300 celebrate club[4169:1061368] Could not inset legal attribution from corner 4
(lldb)

ViewController:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit
import MapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var webview: WKWebView!

@IBOutlet weak var mapview: MKMapView!




override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let url = URL(string: "http://google.com")
    let UrlRequest = URLRequest(url:url!)
    webview.load(UrlRequest) 

}




override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}
```

}

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: use `https://www.google.com` em vez de `http` ou então adiciona o domínio na lista https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30731785/how-do-i-load-an-http-url-with-app-transport-security-enabled-in-ios-9 e troque para caixa baixa `let urlRequest = ...`

Answer (score 1):

Talvez você não tenha ligado o outlet no interface builder.

Se for usar o LocationManager para pegar posicionamento pelo GPS, tem que adicionar permissões no arquivo plist como está explicado aqui no início da documentação:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/choosing_the_authorization_level_for_location_services/requesting_always_authorization

Dependendo do que você deseja, tenha que implementar os métodos delegate do `MKMapViewDelegate`, começando implementar `class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {`